# non-numeric arguments in emacs

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to pass non-numeric argument to functions?

Ex: `C-u 5 M-x eshell` makes(switches to) a eshell with name **`*eshell*<5>`**. But I want to give a name instead of number to eshell buffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is any general way to pass non-numeric arguments to any command the same way `C-u` works.

However, different modes can get input using the minibuffer. For example, `C-u M-x shell` (rather than `eshell`) lets you name your new shell buffer.

You can easily write your own `eshell` command that also lets you name the buffer:

```
(defun eshell-new-buffer (name) 
  (interactive "sBuffer name:")
  (eshell t)
  (rename-buffer name))
```

Then bind it to some key:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c e") 'eshell-new-buffer)
```

Now when you type `C-c e`, you will be prompted for a buffer name and a new `eshell` buffer with that name will be created for you.

Edit: Simplified the code as @sanityinc helpfully pointed out.

Comment: You can simplify that code: make `name` an argument of `eshell-new-buffer`, use `(interactive "sBuffer name: ")`, and then skip the `read-from-minibuffer` step.

Answer (score 0):

Typing <kbd>C-u</kbd> before <kbd>M-x</kbd> sends a *prefix argument* to the command.

Prefix arguments are basically numeric. They *can* be non-numeric, but the possibilities are restricted, and do not include strings. See info node `(elisp) Prefix Command Arguments` for the details.

This means that there is nothing directly analogous to <kbd>C-u</kbd> for passing a string when calling a command *interactively* (for the strict definition of "interactive" in Emacs, where the command's `(interactive)` form is evaluated, generally because you used <kbd>M-x</kbd> to call it). The only way to *interactively* pass a string to a command is if it prompts you for it.

Non-interactively, you can pass any kind of argument to a function, and the simplest way to call an arbitrary function and pass it a string argument is probably this:

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(eshell "foo")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

However this particular example will not have the effect you were hoping for, because the `eshell` function was not written with string arguments in mind.